# windows phone silverlight 8 app system tray color change

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8

I am making a windows phone silverlight 8 app. and I want to change the color of the top system tray throught the application, i.e; during the transition between pages and also when splash screen is visible. is there a way to do it? Please let me know if there is or there isn't.

I already know how to change color on a specific page but that color isn't applied during page transitions and also the splash screen. I want the following colors.

**background: #244421**
**foreground : White**

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows (or via code) for all your pages:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    ...
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
    shell:SystemTray.BackgroundColor="#FF244421"
    shell:SystemTray.ForegroundColor="White">
```

Or you can try defining a resource.

Comment: as I already said this only works on one specific page, I have already done  it, but I want to apply it throughout the application including page transitions and app splash screen. Thankyou